# find expression not working

Tags: find

I would like to convert all powerpoint type files to pdf using the find -exec and unoconv command.

```
find . -name '*.@(ppt|PPT|pptx|PPTX|pps|PPS|ppsm|PPSM|ppsx|PPSX|pptm|PPTM)' -exec unoconv -v -f pdf '{}' \;
```

I have done this before, but since I included the extended pattern matching it does not work. I have tried various options but nothing works. I would appreciate if someone can tell me what I am doing wrong. It just doesn't run.

Answer (score 0):

`find` doesn't support extended pattern matching. Assuming you have a `find` with `-iname` support (like GNU `find`), I'd use something like:

```
find . \( -iname '*.ppt*' -o -iname '*.pps*' \) -exec unoconv -v -f pdf '{}' \;
```

If you're really worried about that matching files incorrectly, you can use more `-o` clauses with more restrictive patterns.

Comment: … or even `-iname '*.pp[st]*'`.